# how should i design my table or what is the alternative?

Tags: website-design, tables

I want to have a table where i dont want to show data repeated. Every column are meant to be treated differently. should I use different tables or what is the better way to show them. Example:

```
|-----------------------------|
|Column1 | Column 2 | Column3 |
|--------|----------|---------|
|dolphin | Rakesh   | social  |
|cat     | Dan brown|         |
|        | Ella     |         |
|        | Ella     |         |
|        | Ella     |         |
|        | Ella     |         |
```

For single `column` I can have repeated data. On above table Ella is repeated if she had a different column1 and column 3 values, it doesn't look fine. for example:

```
|-----------------------------|
|Column1 | Column 2 | Column3 |
|--------|----------|---------|
|dolphin | Ella     | social  |
|cat     | Ella     | social  |
|dolphin | Ella     | Introve |
|        | Ella     |         |
|        | Ella     |         |
|        | Ella     |         |
```

How I can demonstrate it in a table? If I have a data like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some more details and exact examples? This statement seems to be confusing - "As you can see my columns are not related with each other they are related but I will have same column 2 name repeated if column 1 or column3 is different." Are columns related or not?

Comment: I've edited can you please check again?

Comment: @OmkarChogale I've updated the data sample that I want to show

Comment: Is there any relation between Col 1 , 2 & 3?

Comment: no relation at all

Comment: You can group multiple rows to be collapsed and expanded if they have same data. Try AG-grid : https://www.ag-grid.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Ella does not have values in Column1 or Column3, it's redundant (no context and not useful data).

I don't understand the main idea of this data?

What is the objective of presenting it? (I think that the action and visualization must have some purposefulness for the user (e.g. seeing what period is what volunteer is)

---

My idea for data in table:
[image]

It's all depends on the relation – if **"periods"** are corelated with **"volunteers"**

---

If not:

[image]